Tiles from different position from the same coordinates queries StreetView Static API
I'm using StreetView Static API and when i'm querying tiles from the exact same position some tiles does not refer to this position.
My query is :
params = {
            "key": self.api_key,
            "location": f"{50.63188415085098},{3.093636621204306}",
            "fov": config.fov,
            "heading": heading,
            "pitch": pitch,
            "size": "640x640",
            "sources": "google"
        }

response = requests.get({API_URL+KEY", params=params)

With heading in [
40.77169273738318,
75.77169273738318,
5.771692737383177
]
,pitch in [
-15,
-50
]
and location is get from a Metadatas API
As you can see in the provided image (which is the stitching result of the 6 different tiles) some of the elements of the image doesn't fit with the streetview image from the url  (text)
Specially the truck on the image is obviously not supposed to be here.
Retry the queries, same results. I've verify the metadatas api results nothing specific to say the coordinates in the image query correctly fit the ones get from the metadatas api and the status is "OK".
